# Return a list of substrings between instances of a regex statement

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I'm preprocessing the King James Bible for an NLP problem, and would like to retrieve a list of verses in following format:
"XX:XX Text of verse'

The project Gutenberg KJV corpus included in NLTK has verses formatted like that already, but I'm struggling to extract them as substrings.

I've tried constructing a regex statement to extract these substrings, but all I'm getting back is the verse labels (see the code).

```
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg, stopwords
kjv = gutenberg.raw('bible-kjv.txt')

# Get rid of bracketed text
pattern = "[\[].*?[\]]"
kjv = re.sub(pattern, "", kjv)

# Define a regex statement that's supposed to match
# verses in following format: "XX:XX Text of verse"
between_verses = '(\d+:\d+).*[^(\d+:\d+)]*'
result = re.findall(between_verses,kjv[0:500])

print(result)
```

I'm expecting to receive a list like this from my code:

['1:1 In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.',
 '1:2 And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.', ...etc.]

Instead, I'm getting back a list like this:

['1:1','1:2', ...etc.]

Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: FYI: https://regex101.com/ is a nice place to try regexes and get a textual explanation about what you're doing.
In your example, I'm pretty sure that `[^(\d+:\d+)]` is not doing what you expect it to do. It's the same as `[^()\d+:]` because it's a **set** of characters, which is unordered.
Besides, it's good practice to put regexes in raw strings (`r'(my)?Regex'`), see the third paragraph in [the python re manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).
Also, your first regex to remove bracketed text looks overly complicated. You can just use `r'\[.*?\]'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
import re
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg

kjv = gutenberg.raw('bible-kjv.txt')

pattern = re.compile(r"(\d+:\d+.*?)\n\n", re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
res = pattern.findall(kjv)
```

I changed the regular expression so that it would find 'X:X' and then *as few* characters as possible before it found two consecutive newline characters (`\n\n`) which is how the verses are delimited. To switch to the so-called 'non-greedy' regex qualifier just append a `?` after it, e.g. `c*?` (find as few consecutive c's as possible, including none at all).

I also compiled the regular expression beforehand to improve performance when searching through a long text, even though the gain is minimal. Some verses span multiple lines, so I had to set the `MULTILINE` and `DOTALL` flags. The former lets the regex consume more than one line, while the latter lets the `.` capture newline characters, which it usually wouldn't.